# How can I draw this particular phase diagram in Mathematica?

Tags: programming

Sketch the phase diagram for systems with the following velocity functions where `a` and `b` are constants with `b > a > 0`

```
a. dx/dt = a, dy/dt = b
b. dx/dt = a, dy/dt = x
```

Please can someone show me how to draw the phase diagrams for these two functions here?

I know these functions are too simple but this is what we are learning to do in our class right now. So, I'd appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: `StreamPlot` is what I use if the phase space is 2D.  Unfortunately, I don't understand your notation.  But look it up and see if you can figure out how to apply it to your problem.

Comment: @sumonmumu welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! The above systems are too simple. It is very important to understand the mathematical notion of a phase space before you use an advanced software like MMA. Only in that way you will appreciate Mathematics, Physics (dynamics) and MMA.

Comment: First some nitpicking: I believe you meant "phase portrait", "phase diagram" is something that shows up in physical chemistry. Second: do you really need mathematica for this task? Try to find out what dy/dx is by looking at your system of equations...

Answer (score 0):

I place here a more complicated example without the use of `StreamPlot`

Let `x'[t]=y[t]` and `y'[t]=-Sin[x[t]]`

```
T = 10; sol[v_, d_] := 
 NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -Sin[x[t]], x[0] == d, 
   y[0] == v}, {x, y}, {t, -T, T}];
```

and

```
phspace[d0_, v0_, d0step_: Pi, v0step_: 0.5] := ParametricPlot[
  Flatten[
    Table[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol[v, d], {d, -Abs[d0], Abs[d0], 
      d0step}, {v, -Abs[v0], Abs[v0], v0step}]
    , 1] // Evaluate
  , {t, -T, T}, PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-T, T}, {-5, 5}}]

phspace[2 Pi, 3, Pi, 0.5]
```

[image]

StreamPlot contains arrows too! Check:

```
StreamPlot[{y, -Sin[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -3, 3}, AspectRatio -> 3/(2 Pi)]
```